# Show only nonce from registration API

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework

```
this.http.get("/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register").subscribe(data => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data._body));
}, error => {
  console.log("Register get nonce error");
});
```

[image]

How can I get only nonce?

Thank you!

Comment: JSON.parse(data._body).nonce

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do `JSON.parse()` as in ionic 2+, the data are always in JSON format.

Let us suppose you have the object `_body` in your response.

To access the attribute, you can simply do `data._body['nonce']` or `data._body.nonce`

```
this.http.get("/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register").subscribe (data => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data._body));
  console.log(data._body['nonce']);
}, error => {
  console.log("Register get nonce error");
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works!

Comment: How can i do this?